# Save JSON response in Coldfusion

Tags: json, coldfusion

I want to sent push messages with Firebase Cloud Messaging. Everything is working, except for one thing. I want to save the response (see below) from Firebase to update a user profile in the database. So let's say the response gives back a failure, I want to sent that response back to my database.

To sent a push message I use this script:

```
var key = 'my-key';
var to = 'to-key';
var notification = {
   'title': 'Portugal vs. Denmark',
   'body': '5 to 1',
   'icon': 'firebase-logo.png',
   'click_action': 'http://localhost:8081'
};

fetch('https://fcm.googleapis.com/fcm/send', {
   'method': 'POST',
   'headers': {
   'Authorization': 'key=' + key,
   'Content-Type': 'application/json'
},
'body': JSON.stringify({
'notification': notification,
'to': to
 })
 }).then(function(response) {
      console.log(response);
 }).catch(function(error) {
     console.error(error);
 })
```

The response I get back from the Firebase is:
[image: response from firebase]

My question is how can I save (or sent) that response to my coldfusion server. I was thinking of re-writing the script to coldfusion like:

```
 <cfscript>
 objResponse = {
  'message':{
         'to':'SOME_TOKEN',
 'notification':{
    'title': 'Portugal vs. Denmark',
    'body': '5 to 1',
    'icon': 'firebase-logo.png',
    'click_action': 'localhost:8081'
   }
   }
  }
  </cfscript> 

  <Cfdump var="#objResponse#" >
  <cfoutput >#SerializeJSON(objResponse)#</cfoutput>

  <cfhttp url="https://fcm.googleapis.com/fcm/send" method="post" result="objGet">
   <cfhttpparam type="header" name="Accept" value="application/json" />
   <cfhttpparam type="header" name="Authorization" value="key=MY_KEY">
   <cfhttpparam type="header" name="Content-Type" value="application/json" />
   <cfhttpparam type="body"   value='#SerializeJSON(objResponse)#'/>
  </cfhttp>
```

But that is giving me a 400 bad request:

[image]

On https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/http-server-ref#interpret-downstream I found
Only applies for JSON requests. Indicates that the request could not be parsed as JSON, or it contained invalid fields (for instance, passing a string where a number was expected). The exact failure reason is described in the response and the problem should be addressed before the request can be retried.

So I understand it has something to do with the JSON request i'm sending, but I can't figure out what the problem is.

Comment: If you are clientside, use ajax, if serverside, use [`<cfhttp>`](https://helpx.adobe.com/coldfusion/cfml-reference/coldfusion-tags/tags-g-h/cfhttp.html). It's unclear what you are asking. What did you try? What exactly do you need help with?

Comment: That's not ColdFusion code, you are not doing anything "in ColdFusion" here. Can you be more precise?

Comment: I have update the question.

Comment: When a question is edited, which completely changes the code you’re having problems with, best to create a new question.

Answer (score 3):

Since you are making this request from javascript in your browser, you would need to add some code in the `.then()` callback that would make an ajax post request to your ColdFusion server, sending the data you want to save.

Not sure what your flow is here, but you could also make the http request from the ColdFusion server itself.

Comment: The original question’s code was completely changed, which makes this answer irrelevant.